# How to see the whole file with vi command in Linux

Tags: linux

When I did

```
grep 'middleware' file.log
```

It turned up a line containing middleware.

But when I did `vi Filename.log` on the linux server, I could not find my contents.

Please tell me how to see the whole file with vi file.log

Comment: Did you try to search in vi? Do you know how to "navigate" (page up/down)?

Comment: If the match was in file.log, why would you expect to see it in Filename.log?

Answer (score 2):

You want to view the result of `grep 'middleware' file.log` in vi, right?
If yes, try this:

```
grep 'middleware' file.log | vi -
```

You can search inside vi typing a `/`, example: `/middleware`, and going forward with `n`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the search function in vi (or vim which is more likely what you are running).  In command mode, type / and the regular expression you want to search for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'grep -n' to show the line number on which the pattern matches, and then navigate to that line within vi using:

```
$ vi +N file.log # (where N is the line number on which the match was found)
```

or just type 'NG' to go to line N.  (eg, 123G will take you to line 123)

(note: +N syntax on the command line is valid in vim.  I'm not sure about classic vi.)